# Pass special charactor to button from variable

Tags: html, svelte

```
var text = '&lsaquo;';
    
<button>{text}</button>
```

This doesn't show `‹` but `&lsaquo;` as the button's text.

This works of course:

```
<button>&lsaquo;</button>
```

How to pass this as a variable?

Comment: <button>{{text}}</button> try this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [`{@html ...}`  tag](https://svelte.dev/docs#html).

```
<button>{@html text}</button>
```

However, you need to be careful with this method if the string contains a user-inputted value.

Answer (score 0):

@html is dangerous and could lead to security vulnerabilities. use this decode function.

```js
const decode = function (html) {
    const txt = document.createElement('textarea');
    txt.innerHTML = html;
    return txt.value;
};
```

before rendering the text. [Here](https://svelte.dev/repl/2e43a7aeb76744eb9662c70ccb952578?version=3.32.3) is a complete svelte repl working example.